# Making additional (custom) metadata available for a field

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

I am looking for a way to add additional metadata to object fields for use by some Salesforce and non-Salesforce UI code. What I need is a small piece of custom JSON per field. (Yes I could create a separate custom API to deliver this data.)

The "Description" looked like a candidate place to put the JSON, but that is not exposed in e.g. these APIs:

```
/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/Account/describe

/services/data/v46.0/ui-api/record-ui/a0F2F000002BhtV
```

I could add the info on the end of the "Help Text" (`inlineHelpText`) but would then need to strip that off.

Is there an API that returns the "Description" of a field along with the rest of the field metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such an API, or any other way of extending standard metadata like this. I think you might be forced into:

- Storing the values you require as some Custom Metadata Type, with a 'Key' field that holds the Object and Field API names for querying.
- Storing the values in some global utility class, with each JSON string being a value in a Map of `<String, String>` where the key is Object + Field API name.

Comment: Thanks Dan, yep I think I'm stuck.